# Stop playing video when detected image is not captured anymore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I'm creating an AR app to detect images on a cube (there are 6 images printed on the cube). Based on the detected image a related video is being played. Unfortunately the AVplayer doesn't stop playing the video even if another picture is recognized --> it can happen that multiple videos are getting played at the same time (not super bad for the video but especially the overlapping audio is horrible).

My assumption was that following function will actually stop the currently played video but nothing happens --> even if the cube is not captured by the camera anymore the audio continues.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

    if let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ARImages", bundle: Bundle.main) {

        configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 6
    }

    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    sceneView.session.pause()
    //sceneView?.removeFromSuperview()
}

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
        let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
        let fileUrlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp4") else {return}

    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrlString))

    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoItem)
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

    player.play()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        player.play()

    }

    let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 960, height: 720))
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
    videoNode.yScale = -1.0
    videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to call a "player.pause()" or "player.stop()" function that stops playing the video when the captured image is not detected anymore?

appreciate your support!

Comment: You need to replace video in AVPlayer, thats what I did. Can we see the code for adding video?

Comment: Hi Alok,
I added the code to original Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I have not checked this with audio (somehow my device stopped playing audio). You have different instances of AVPlayer playing video for different image nodes. So I just took them out so same player will have new video for different nodes

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var videoScene: SKScene!
var videoNode: SKVideoNode!
var url: String!

func setupVideoNode(){
    videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

    player.play()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        self.player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        self.player.play()

    }
    videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 960, height: 720))
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
    videoNode.yScale = -1.0
    videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
        let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
        let fileUrlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp4") else {return}
        url = fileUrlString

    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrlString))

    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: videoItem) //= AVPlayer(playerItem: videoItem)

    setupVideoNode()

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
        let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
        let fileUrlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp4") else {return}

    if url == fileUrlString{
        return
    }
    url = fileUrlString
    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrlString))
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: videoItem)
    player.play()
}
```